# Как нормализовать гистограмму pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, анализ-данных, статистика, гистограммы

Х​очу построить гистограмму распределения среднего выборки для экспоненциального распределения через pyplot hist.

Параметр `density` выставил на `True`. Согласно документации, именно он должен нормализовать гистограмму к 1. Однако, результат мне непонятен:

```
expon_rv = sts.expon(loc = 0, scale = 1)
sample = expon_rv.rvs(1000)

n2 = 10
sample_2_mean = []
for k in range(1000):
    sample_2 = np.random.choice(sample, n2)
    sample_2_mean.append(np.mean(sample_2))

plt.hist(sample_2_mean, bins = 20, density = True)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не дочитали документацию: `If stacked is also True, the sum of the histograms is normalized to 1.` Или я не так понял ваше: `нормализовать гистограмму к 1`?

Comment: По сути мне нужна плотность распределения, по идее она не должна  превышать, я про это

Comment: а почему вы решили, что площадь всех прямоугольников превышает 1? ;)

Comment: вообще никак, но мне нужно, чтобы отображалась доля

Comment: какая доля и чтобы как/где отображалась?

Comment: Если при выводе выставить density = False, то на гистограмме по оси у будет абсолютное число вхождений в данный интервал. А мне вместо абсолютных чисел нужна доля вхождение по у

Comment: ну так на вашем графике все так и есть - по оси `Y` - "доля" вхождений

Comment: А почему она больше 1?

Comment: Кто она? Суммарная площадь? Так она не больше - она равна 1 ;)

Comment: В плане доля в районе 1 равна 1,4

Answer (score 2):

При указании [параметра `density=True`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) - суммарная **площадь** прямоугольников  будет равна единице. Т.е. вы получаете *график плотности вероятностей*. Если перемножить высоту на ширину каждого прямоугольника и сложить все полученные площади - мы должны получить `1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, товарищу нужно что-то типа этого:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter
import scipy.stats as sts

expon_rv = sts.expon(loc = 0, scale = 1)
sample = expon_rv.rvs(1000)

n2 = 10
sample_2_mean = []
for k in range(1000):
    sample_2 = np.random.choice(sample, n2)
    sample_2_mean.append(np.mean(sample_2))

weights = [x/sum(sample_2_mean) for x in sample_2_mean]
plt.hist(sample_2_mean, bins = 20, weights=weights)
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1)) #для отображения в процентах, а не в долях
```

получится:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]